# If three functions in commutative diagram are bijection, is the fourth one too?

Tags: linear-algebra, commutative-algebra, diagram-chasing

Let's say we have a commutative diagram as in the following picture. The functions $f, h, g$ are all bijections. Can we conclude that $k$ is also a bijection?

I need this as part of my proof, but in my opinion, we can only conclude that, since $k \circ g = h \circ f$ and $h \circ f$ is a bijection (composition of bijections is a bijection), then $k$ is surjective (and $g$ is injective, but we already know this).

Is it possible to conclude that $k$ is also injective, because this is a part of a proof in linear algebra, and our professor told us to check for ourselves that $k$ is a bijection?

[image: Generic commutative diagram]

Comment: Note you can reverse arrows using inverses.

Comment: @user10354138 What do you mean by reverse arrows; then I would need inverses, but we don't know yet, if an inverse of $k$ exists?

Comment: Notice that all this holds in every category. Replace bijection by isomorphism.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I don't know anything about category theory yet. This is from introductory course to Linear Algebra. But yes, $h$ and $g$ are supposed to be isomorphisms. Thank you anyways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$k\circ g=h\circ f$ and by assumption $f,g,h$ are bijective (equivalently invertible, which also means their inverses are bijections), so $k=h\circ f\circ g^{-1}$ is a composition of bijections, hence a bijection.